# trying to display value returns undefinded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

HTML:

```
<span class="rbx-text-navbar-right text-header" id="nav-robux-amount">11</span>
```

CODE:

```
element = document.getElementById("nav-robux-amount")

if (element){
    window.alert(element.value)
}
```

window.alert shows that the value of element is undefined

Comment: the value of element is not undefined the property value on the dom element does not exist. You need textContent.

Comment: span is not a form element.

Answer (score 1):

The `.value` property only exists on inputs.
The 'element' isn't a constant variable.

If you want to get the content, you can do the following:

```
const element = document.getElementById("nav-robux-amount");

if (element) window.alert(element.textContent)
```

Note: innerHTML is not as good as textContent, as it is vulnerable to attacks.